# Application Halt for OCUnit TestCase and give error message

Tags: iphone, ipad

Code is from ClassMessage written:

```
 -(void)showMessage:(Message*) msg
    {
        if( msg == nil )
        {
            return;
        }

    UIAlertView* alertView;
    if(msg.url)
    {
        alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msg.title
                                      message:msg.message
                                      delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:msg.buttonLabel1
                                      otherButtonTitles:msg.buttonLabel2
                                      , nil];

    }
    else
    {
        alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msg.title
                                         message:msg.message
                                         delegate:self
                                         cancelButtonTitle:msg.buttonLabel1
                                         otherButtonTitles:nil];
    }

    [alertView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Writing the Unit Test Case for the above method!

```
-(void)testShowMessageMessageURL{

    Message *testMessage = [[Message alloc] init];

    testMessage.messageId = 1000 ;
    testMessage.message = @"Error message";
    testMessage.title = @"Error Title";
    testMessage.url = @"http://.……….";
    testMessage.buttonLabel1 = @"OK";
    testMessage.buttonLabel2 = @"Cancel";
    testMessage.buttonLabel2 = nil;

       @try {

ClassMessage *testClass = [[ClassMessage alloc]init];

if(testMessage.url != nil){

STAssertNoThrow([testClass showMessage:testMessage],@"Should Pass ");

}

}
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Exception Name %@, Exception Description %@",[exception name],[exception description]);
        STFail(@"Should not caught Exception");
    }
}
```

The Application Halt Is

```
CoreFoundation`__HALT:
0xa40880:  int3   
0xa40881:  nopw   %cs:(%eax,%eax)

Thread 1: EXC_BreakPoint(code = EXC_i386_BPT,subcode = 0*0)
```

After Clicking continue program Execution

I got the error message
Error Message is:

```
[testClass showMessage:testMessage] raised -[_NSCFType pointSize]: unrecognized selector sent to instance should not throws any exception.
```

I do have this issue when covering my test case.

Any one advice me what i did wrong to cover my test Case?
@Thanks in advance

Comment: Ever figure this out? Having the same issue with alert views